# Access Query Find All records Where all Linked Records Match

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tables:

```
tblStudents:
ID, Student Name
1, John
2, Mark
3, Fred

tblEnrolledSubjects:
ID, Student ID, Subject ID, Score
1, 1, 1, 75
2, 1, 2, 75
3, 1, 3, 75
4, 1, 4, NULL
5, 2, 1, 75
6, 3, 1, 75
7, 3, 2, 80
8, 3, 3, 85

tblSubject:
ID, Subject Name
1, Maths
2, English
3, Science
4, History
```

I want to return all distinct students that have a score of over (say 70) for all subjects. SELECT [Student Name]

Students can be enrolled in 1 or more subjects.
If a student has even one subject not of required score then they should not be listed.

From he above data I would expect to see

```
Mark
Fred
```

What would the SQL query be for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `NULL` value doesn't count against you, then

```
SELECT tblStudents.[Student Name]
FROM tblEnrolledSubjects RIGHT JOIN tblStudents 
    ON tblEnrolledSubjects.[Subject ID] = tblStudents.ID
GROUP BY tblStudents.[Student Name]
HAVING (Min(tblEnrolledSubjects.[Score])>=70);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.Studentname
  FROM tblStudents t JOIN
      (select count(*) cnt, min(nz(score,0)) minscore, StudentID
         FROM tblEnrolledSubjects
     GROUP BY StudentID) s
   ON t.Studentid = s.studentid
WHERE minscore>=70 --if mark is greater than or equal to 70
```

Comment: but if a student is only enrolled in three classes (but has good marks in all three), your SQL will exclude him from the results simply because he is not enrolled in all five classes.  I'm not sure this was the intent.  I would remove that part of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Yes if that doesn't matters then we have to remove the where clause that checks the count